How to switch between uppercase and lowercase in apps other than MS Word?
In Microsoft Word, there is an incredibly useful tool under the keyboard shortcut Shift+F3. When you select a piece of text and press these keys, the text changes from lowercase to uppercase, the next time you press it, only the first letters become uppercase and the next time you press it, everything goes back to where it started. And the best thing about it is that it works with different characters, whether I write the text in Russian, Hungarian or Polish.
The problem is that, apart from Word, this keyboard shortcut is nowhere to be found, and I have tried many times to find some solution to this problem (preferably one that works under Windows, macOS and Linux, but, for example, a simple Chrome plug-in wouldn't be the worst solution either).
Does anyone have any ideas about a keyboard shortcut tool where I could set something like this up, or any other solution?




You'll need a general keyboard shortcut app for Windows. They are out there.  https://www.solveyourtech.com/how-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-11-a-comprehensive-guide/

+1 for mentioning that useful shortcut, which works in LibreOffice, as well. Notepad++ uses Shift-U/Ctrl-Shift-U, but those shortcuts can be remapped. However, this is not just a keyboard shortcut,  but a shortcut to a macro in that application, and not all apps have that ability.

You could script it as always with AHK, but ofc it'll require some decent effort.

In Word, it is not to a macro, but to a built-in command. This may be a matter of jargon, I suppose. NotePad does not run macros.
